# Cannot modify or delete labels from TFS Project in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, tfvc

I have been trying to modify or delete labels from a branch that uses TFVC (Team Foundation Version Control) for source control and is part of a Azure DevOps project.

It seems that it allows me to create, modify or delete labels that were created with my user, but I cannot do that if the creator was another member.

This is error that I'm getting:

[image]

I have already set those permissions through TF Command-Line but isn't working. I requested my PM to make member of the Project Administrators group in the ADO Project, but that didn't help either.

[image]

There are the permissions that the ADO group currently has:

[image]

I should be working but I don't know why it keeps showing me that error.

Any help or guidance woulde be appreciate.

Thank you.

---

Edit -> 2020-05-19

I checked the individuals permissions from my user as @Levi Lu-MSFT told me, I tried changing it but I can't due to inheritance from another group that I'm member of.
At least, we could finally found the problem but I don't know how to avoid overwriting and proceed.

[image]

Comment: Can you check the permission setting of your own account for the TFVC repo? Your permission setting can be overrode even you are in the project administrator group.

Comment: Do you know how to do that? Do I have to use TF Command-Line? I've already tried "/user" param with the tf permission command, but seems like it omits it. Thank you.

Comment: You check your permission from the UI page Repositories security. See below screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if your permission settings is overrode for the TFVC repo.

Go the  **Projecet Settings**-->**Repositories**-->**Click** the TFVC repo-->**Search** for your user account-->**Check** if the permissions are set to **Allow**

[image]

Comment: Thank you really much. I have finally found the problem, a permission value was being inherited from another group that my user was member of. I don't know why I couldn't see that in the TF Command Line.

Comment: I'm trying to change that permission value but it doesn't allow me to save changes. I keeps overwriting it with inheritance, it's getting the value from project Contributors Group. Do you know how to avoid that?

Comment: If the permission is Deny inherited from contributors group. You need to change the contributors group to `Not set` or remove your account out from Contributors group. It is by design that inherited deny permission cannot be overwrote.

Comment: Thank you really much, that did I trick. I thought that if you are member of Project Adminstrators Group those permission would supersede lower permissions like the ones from Contributos Group.